# How can we use a mobx store in utility function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

How can we use a mobx store in utility function?
I have a mobx store and a utility function to make a axio call, I want to use stote value in the utility, how can I do this?

```js
// Store example

export default class SampleStore {
  @observable title = "Coding is Love";
 
  @observable user = {
    userId: 1,
  };
 
  @action
  setUser(user) {
    this.user = user;
  }
 
  @action
  updateUser(data) {
    this.user = { ...this.user, ...data };
  }
 
  @action
  clearUser() {
    this.user = undefined;
  }
 
  @action
  setTitle(title) {
    this.title = title;
  }
}


// Utility function in different file 

export function makeApiCall () {
  // Use SampleStore here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you actually initialize your store, how your app is organized and many other factors.

Most simple way is to have singleton store and then you just import it and use directly:

```
// export an instance instead
export const sampleStore = new SampleStore()

// .. util fil
import { sampleStore } from './SampleStore.js'

export function makeApiCall () {
  sampleStore.setUser()
}
```

Another way is just to pass store to the function, for example if you want to make this call inside `useEffect` or something:

```
// Make function accept store as an argument
export function makeApiCall (sampleStore) {
  sampleStore.setUser()
}

// ... inside of some React component
// get store from the context (I guess you will have it at that point)
const { sampleStore } = useStores()

useEffect(() => {
  // and just pass to the function
  makeApiCall(sampleStore)
}, [])
```